# Enterprise Library Database Trace Listener?

Tags: enterprise-library

I'm using EntLib v4 for Logging and currently I'm saving the events to the default text file listener.

I would like to use MS SQL database as my event sink and I saw that the database listener is already provided, but I don't know how to create logging database and stored procedures?

After googling around I saw that in v3 the database creation scripts were shipped with the EntLib, but I can't find them in v4.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just checked and its in the installation for the source.  On my machine its in `C:\EntLib4Src\Blocks\Logging\Src\DatabaseTraceListener\Scripts`.

You can use the createloggingdb.cmd file or parse loggingdatabase.sql yourself for the relevant commands.